Find the matrix representation of T relative to the bases
Let T: P2→ P2 be a linear transformation such that T(p(x)) = xp'(x) + 2p(x). Find the matrix representation of T relative to the bases B = {1, 1+ x, 1 + x + x²}, B' = {-1 + x, -1 + x+ x², x}for P2

You have not defined $P_2$. You have not made clear whether $B,B'$ are bases of the domain and/or image. We should not have to guess. If you did make these things clear, you must know what the definition of a  matrix is, so where exactly are you stuck?

First show your try. Hint: how do you construct the matrix of transformation relative to any basis?

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem, so it can be reopened.
